# Convergence of sequence of random variables 2

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

> If I know $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n<c-\gamma)=0$ for all $\gamma>0$, how can I prove supremum of all reals $\alpha$ for which $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n\leq \alpha)=0$ is greater than or equal to $c$?

I think $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n<c-\gamma)=0$ for all $\gamma>0$ yields $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n<c)=0$. Now, if I can prove this means $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n\leq c)=0$, then I am all set. But, the problem is that this last step is not valid.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq c)=0$. Instead, let 
$$A=\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}:\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq \alpha)=0\} $$
and observe that if $\alpha<c$, then there exists $\gamma>0$ such that $\alpha<c-\gamma<c$, hence 
$$\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq \alpha)\leq \mathbb{P}(X_n<c-\gamma)$$
for all $n$, so
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq \alpha)\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n<c-\gamma)=0 $$
so $\alpha\in A$. Therefore $A$ contains the interval $(-\infty,c)$, so $\sup A\geq c$.